# Kafka - Error on specific consumer -Broker not available

Tags: apache-kafka

We have deployed multiple Kafka consumers in container's clusters.  All are working properly except for one, which is throwing warning "Connection to node 0 could not be established. Broker may not be available", however, this error appears only in one of the containers, and this consumer is running in the same network and server of the others. So I have ruled out issues with kafka server configuration.
I tried changing the groupid of the consumer and I got it working for some minutes, but now warn is appearing again.  I consume all topics used by this consumer from a bash shell and I can consume.
Having into account the above context, I think it could be due to bad practice in the consumer software code, also, it could be about offsets got damaged. How could I identify if are there some of this kind using kafka logs?

Comment: You'd have to show your code if you think something is bad there

Answer (score 0):

You can exec into the container and netcat the broker's advertised addresses to verify connectivity.

You can also use the Kafka shell scripts to verify consuming functionality, as always.

Corrupted offsets would prevent any consumer from reading, not only one. Bad code practices wouldn't show up in logs

If you have the container running "on same server as others", I'd suggest working with affinity rules and constraints to spread your applications onto multiple servers before placing on the same machine